# Error installing ruby bundle in textmate

Tags: ruby, textmate2

I have Textmate 2.0-beta.7.1 on Mac OSX v10.9.5
I would like to write ruby scripts so I installed the ruby bundle.

However when I try to run a script I get the error:

```
env: ruby18: No such file or directory
```

so having found that the path to my ruby installation using

```
which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I made sure this was in my variable paths in Textmate>Preferences> Variables so that it under the PATH variable name it looked like this:

```
 $PATH:/usr/bin/ruby:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin
```

I then tried to run my ruby script again and I got the same error. I have googled for hours and the only resolution seems to be the addition of the ruby path to $PATH as I have done above so I'm a bit confused as to my I cant proceed

Comment: Did you try reverting to defaults? https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Reverting-To-Defaults

Comment: I thought about it but that means erasing all the stuff I've configured. Surely there's a better way than a reboot of textmate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have not disabled the Bundle Support, TextMate, Text, Source, or SCM bundles in the Bundles tab of Preferences; these are all required bundles to support basic bundle functions.

Comment: I had unticked some of these. Now its sorted. Thanks so much

Comment: Lovely. This was driving me mad.